Why use Ionic router instead of other JS framework's router?
I started trying a hybrid mobile app with Ionic/Capacitor.
I don't really know what benefits the Ionic router provides, what it does for me and what the Vue router can't do?

I would suggest you use react native for cross platform mobile app development. Remember IonReactRouter uses React Router library. The benefits of IonReact Router is that you can create multi-page apps with rich page transitions

Thank you Thomas, but I prefer Vue to React.
And you say only transitions what Ionic router gives?

bad advice and it's irrelevant.
